# Interrupt read() on signal

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I have a thread that continuously reads a serial port for data.
If the main program receives a SIGINT it calls g_thread_join() on the serial port thread.

However, since the read is blocking the serial port thread won't return and program stalls untill i get a byte on the serial line and then it can exit.

Is there a way to pass the SIGINT on to read() so that it can be forced to return when the main thread demands it?

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522277/how-can-i-implement-timeout-for-read-when-reading-from-a-serial-port-c-c  -- it shows you how to read with a timeout, so the SIGINT will eventually be acted upon

Comment: You should have some event loop and use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Comment: No, you can't pass a signal to a thread. Instead use timed read (above), or use eventfd() or similar to poll on two descriptors and use one of them to wake up.

Comment: With `pthread_kill` you can pass a signal to a thread. This can indeed be used to interrupt a `read`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523146/487509) for this previous question on [implementing timeout for read() when reading from a serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522277/how-can-i-implement-timeout-for-read-when-reading-from-a-serial-port-c-c) shows how to use [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to perform reading with timeout. The SIGINT signal you send will thus be eventually acted upon.

Answer (score 5):

To have `read()` return `EINTR`, unset `SA_RESTART` in the member `sa_flags` of the `struct sigaction` passed into the call to [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) when installing the signal handler for `SIGINT`.

---

An alternative approach woud be to avoid a blocking `read()` at all. Please see the answers to this question: [how to avoid blocking from the read function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21800118/694576)

Comment: I did not get it to work when just clearing SA_RESTART. Are there any pitfalls to watch out for in using that method, do you know? Thanks!

Comment: @evading: Seeing the source you implemented your solution with would help a lot.